# Why is the inhabitant of a country called a “citizen”, instead of a "countrizen"?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Why is *citizen* used to describe an inhabitant of a country when the word is derived from the Latin for city (*civitas*) and originally meant a city dweller?

Wouldn’t the nouns derived from ‘country’ or ‘nation’ (national) be more appropriate?

Comment: Although the [etymology of the word](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=citizen) has links to *city*, perhaps we can chalk the broadening to semantic drift. The word [*countryman*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/countryman) might be closer to what you're looking for, though.

Comment: Perhaps it is because in ancient Greece a city (polis) was also a state - and we have inherited the concept of citizenship from them. In contrast, the concept of nation state is quite recent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange English Language & Usage. :0)  ==> Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This would have made a good question if the OP had avoided exclamation maks, CAPS, and an aggressive tone. @DogLover has done a very good job at editing this post, along with adding  "national" I would have left the OP's suggested **countrizen*.  The OP has seemingly vanished, it has attracted 4 downvotes... what to do... vote to reopen. No question like this has been asked before.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for your kind words. I agree that the original post had a very aggressive tone, so I had to rectify that along with the poor presentation. I was going to edit it last night, but I couldn't really be bothered so I made sure to do it today. I'll update the edit to include "countrizen". Oh, and yes, I think it should be reopened now that it's civil, unique and question-worthy.

Comment: The question may be derived from a distinction in the original asker's mother tongue. Japanese is probably not that mother tongue, but Japanese does make a distinction -- *kokumin* (person of the country), *kenmin* (person of the prefecture), and *shimin* (person of the city). However, in Japanese, the distinction is not about the person, but about the laws being applied. These words are all more about residence than citizenship.

Comment: Why doesn't a hypothetical word exist? How can that possibly be a suitable question for SE EL&U? Can this possibly have any answer other than a subjective speculation? If the question asked about the historical origin of the word and whether it displaced other words previously in use, then there could be objective answers, but this is madness.

Comment: @David The OP is asking why the term *citizen* is used. There's nothing mad about asking [*why* one term](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Betymology%5D+title%3Awhy+%22and+not%22) is preferred to another

Comment: @Mari-LouA — the madness doesn't refer to the question but to considering it appropriate. I appreciate that you were trying to be helpful by editing it, but while the reference to countrizens remains it is still an embarassment imho. And it's not clear whether the question has been recast to ask about contemporary usage of citizen v. national, or the origin of the word in English in relation to urban or rural populations. I actually don't think the OP meant either: he appears to be a non-native speaker intrigued by the Latin origin of the word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — but to show that I have a heart of gold (and as a diversion from writing responsive web pages) I have answered the question. Or at least a question. I suggest that the question be revised along the lines I indicate, but one step at a time.

Comment: @David bravo for answering, let's see if someone else thinks the answer should be rewritten and wants to follow your suggestion. Please look at the edit history to see how the post has been tidied up, the revised version you see is the effort of Dog Lover, I only modified the original  title. but I'd like to think I have respected the OP's request.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  As a denizen in my own neck of the woods, I think I'm far better off than I was as a citizen elsewhere.

Comment: I have change the question so that it relates to actual English words (countryman or -woman rather than countrizen) and is of a standard I would consider belongs here rather than on ELL. This is not the version in my answer, which I have now modified. I think this should be acceptable to all.

Comment: @David you've completely changed the nature of the question, it is now a question set by a competent native speaker. It's one thing fixing grammatical errors, and rewording poorly structured phrases, it's quite another thing to give it a total "makeover". The question was fine as it was, it was acceptable, the close votes had been cast before Dog Lover had tidied it up, no one else was bothered because it made sense. Muh... *shrugs shoulders*

Comment: Talking of votes cast to close, there are none now. So who was troubled by the question, apart from you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA — We obviously disagree.

Comment: I.Can't.Let.It.Go.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — I don't see why. After all the tour says "Improve posts by editing or commenting". You've been here longer than me, but you're not a mod. And the poster has clearly lost interest, isn't a native speaker and shouldn't be posting on a site "for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". However, it's not worth fighting over. Someone needs to explain that English nouns of this type are not formed by adding "izen", but by adding "man", and that there is no clear understanding of how the "izen" in "citizen" arose. I will amend my answer to deal with this.

Comment: @David Since the post was edited, the question earned two upvotes, as did your answer. You should be fairly satisfied.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — Oh yes. And although I find your attitude a bit infuriating, I can't get mad as you're not aggressive with it. (sexist remark deleted)

Answer (score 4):

OED has a note on citizen:

> The semantic development has been influenced by classical Latin cīvis (see civic adj.)

It seems like the semantic drift in citizen, civilian, civic, etc. from "city-dweller" to one with legal rights within any governed community involves both legal and military history.

In an early shift, it seemed to refer to legal disputes between private individuals as opposed to a military or criminal dispute.

> **civil plea** a legal proceeding relating to civil law, as opposed to criminal or (formerly) ecclesiastical law; a plea brought in a civil court, a civil action.

Following that angle, the importance of membership to a city vs. membership in any society became less important than the law under which a citizen dispute occurred.

Given the importance of Latin in these etymologies, I wouldn't be surprised if references to "citizens of Rome" led to some ambiguity. (Rome is the object in the oldest dated reference to general social membership in OED's cited uses -- from a bible translation.)

Answer (score 3):

**Summary**

The English word ‘citizen’ is of Anglo-Norman vintage and was initially used to mean a city dweller, but soon acquired the current alternative meaning, which eventually became dominant. ‘Countryman’ (not ‘countrizen’) is the noun derived from ‘country’, but acquired a slightly different meaning as illustrated by ‘fellow countryman’, and was able to exist in concert with ‘citizen’. ‘Countryman’ can also be used to mean someone with a rural abode, so is no less ambiguous. ‘National’ has only been used as a noun in this sense more recently and is often used with a different shade of meaning. Whether or not the alternatives would have been more appropriate is a matter of opinion, but no native speaker cares.

**Origin and use of ‘citizen’**

According to the 1928 edition of the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), the first meaning of the word was a city dweller:

> 1. An inhabitant of a city or (often) a town ; esp. one possessing civic rights and privileges, a burgess or freeman of a city.

…and the first example it quotes illustrates this

> “1314…Þe citiseins of Þat cite wel often god Þonked he”

There follows an example from 1514 in which ‘citizen’ is used in explicit contrast to ‘countryman’ — meaning a rural dweller. (It is also used in contrast to soldier.) Another such example is as late as the 19th century, but I suspect the modern meaning had overtaken it by then.

The more usual modern meaning is given by the OED as

> 2. A member of a state, an enfranchised inhabitant of a country, as opposed to an alien…

and the first example quoted occurs less than a century after that of the original meaning, associating a citizen with a region rather than a city:

> “ *c* 1384 In this Region certeyn Duelleth many a Citezeyn…”

The association of rights and privileges with the original meaning of ‘citizen’ suggests to me that the extension of the word may have seemed acceptable because it implied not where one lived, but the rights and privileges that were a consequence of one's nationality. (But this is just a suggestion.)

**Origin and use of alternatives derived from the word ‘country’**

The OP clearly feels that a noun derived from the word ‘country’ would be more appropriate than one derived from ‘city’, but is wide of the mark in suggesting ‘countrizen’. The suffix ‘izen’ is not used to form a noun for inhibitant in English in any other case (see the OED entry for ‘citizen’) and there is, in fact, a word formed from ‘country’ in the normal manner of adding ‘man’ (sometimes with a feminine form ‘woman’) — **countryman**.

Indeed, according to the OED, the use of ‘countryman’ to indicate an inhabitant of a particular nation predates that same use for ‘citizen’, with the first example cited in 1305. The definition given:

> 1. A man of a (specified or indicated) country or district… ; a native or inhabitant, often in comb…

This usage has more or less died out expect in relation to districts, e.g. “north-countryman”.

More common is the similar but distinct usage (first OED example 1425):

> 2. A man of one’s own country, a fellow-countryman ; usually with possesive

This co-existed with citizen because they were used in different ways. e.g.

> “I was supported by my *countrymen*, stalwart English *citizens* all.” *(my contrived
>   example)*

In addition, ‘countryman’ was no less ambiguous than ‘citizen’, as from 1577, or earlier, there was (as already alluded) the meaning”

> 3. One who lives in the country or rural parts and follows a rural occupation ; a husbandman

**Origin and use of ‘a national’**

A [Google ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A+British+citizen%2CA+British+national&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CA%20British%20citizen%3B%2Cc0) of “a British citizen” and “a British national” finds almost no examples of the latter. (Similar results are obtained substituting ‘American’ for ‘British’.) This just emphasizes the less frequent use of ‘national’ (noun) compared with ‘citizen’. The first example cited by the OED in its modern sense is from the late 19th century when it was clearly a neologism:

> 4. *pl.* in recent diplomatic use (after Fr *nationaux*) : Persons belonging to the same nation ; (one’s) fellow-countrymen.

with the example:

> “1887 Each of these Consuls or Ministers has extensive power over his
>   own nationals”

This illustrates the tendency to use the term in situations in which people are living in a country other than that for which they hold nationality.

To complicate things further, there is a formal difference between *British Citizenship* and *British Nationality*, which is explained on the [Government website](https://www.gov.uk/types-of-british-nationality/overview). I am not aware that the such a distinction exists in the US.

**Why citizen?**

I’m not sure that this is a very useful type of question. Of course, in some circumstances one can trace the displacement of one word by another to specifics, such as television or the internet. However, in many cases a word is introduced into a language, changes its meaning, and nobody worries about what it originally meant.

As I have explained, there was a word ‘countryman’, related to the noun ‘country’, but this was and is used in a slightly different sense, and, with its rural connotation, is no less ambiguous than ‘citizen’.

The word ‘national’ may be less ambiguous, but arrived much later on the scene, probably, as already mentioned by others, because the idea of a nation state arose much later.

**Footnote for British citizens (and others)**

The British Prime Minister, Teresa May, may have [said](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/10/05/theresa-mays-conference-speech-in-full/):

> “But if you believe you’re *a citizen of the world*, you’re a citizen of
>   nowhere.”

However this extended use of citizen (“One who is at home and claims his rights everywhere”) was used in Britain as early as 1474, according to the OED:

> “Helde hym bourgeys and cytezeyn of the world.”

Of course Cicero was using it (in Latin) — [*civem totius mundi*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TlgsB9gcRmEC&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=Cicero+civem+totius+mundi&source=bl&ots=6mYdJh3JM-&sig=dbsCHFGh2RNGtc06Ndb_0RbMPiM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7ooqHlqDVAhXB2BoKHTBTAD0Q6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=Cicero%20civem%20totius%20mundi&f=false) — long before then.

Comment: If you extend your ngrams search to include ["a British subject"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+British+subject%2Ca+British+citizen%2Ca+British+national&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20British%20subject%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20British%20citizen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20British%20national%3B%2Cc0) you'll see that subject was used far more frequently than either citizen or national until very recently.

Comment: @Bob — Yes, but that is specifically British — because of the British citizen's relationship to the monarch. However I'm not sure what it has to do with the relative historical use of citizen and national, which was what the question and answer were about.

Comment: The OP doesn't specifiy which flavour of English they're interested in, but you can't really discuss the use of "citizen" to mean "national" in British English (which you brought up) without mentioning the very recent move away from the use of "subject" in favour of "citizen". This has happened for a number of reasons, not least the way the legal definitions of "national", "citizen" and "subject" in the UK and commonwealth have changed at various points in the last hundred years or so. There's a wealth of legal, political, and social history behind this question.

Comment: @Bob — in this case US and British usage is similar so to understand how the use of citizen arose one is obliged to go back to Anglo-Norman. A more relevant alternative to native would be countryman, which I intend to address more fully. And you might consider whether my intensively researched and documented answer might be worth up voting.

Comment: Further and (I hope) final revision adding more detail on the word 'countryman' and correcting previous erroneous assertion that it initially meant a rural dweller.

Answer (score 0):

it's a matter of common contemporary usage. Citizenship can refer to a legally recognized subject of a town, city, county country, or planet. In the USA most people would be clueless as to the meaning of "national."

Comment: I'm not in the US, but to me "national" is a bit of a "news" term. For example, *an American national* is something that you might see in a newspaper, online or otherwise.

Comment: "National" is also a legal term which does not imply citizenship.

Comment: I think it is clear from the question that by "why" the OP means how did this usage arise, not what is the motivation of contemporary users for employing the term. It may be a poor question, but you do not answer it.